# HTTP Digest authentication using KSOAP-2

Tags: android

I want to use HTTP Digest authentication using KSOAP-2. 
I have found out how we can do Basic Authentication. 
But I could not find any reference to Digest Authentication. 
Can anybody help me in this regard?

Thanks in advnace :)

Thanks and regards,
Aashish Sharma

Answer (score 1):

According to the KSoap2 changelog since version 3.6.1 of ksoap2-android supports using OKHttp as HTTP transport.

For OkHttp there is the extension [okhttp-digest](https://github.com/rburgst/okhttp-digest) that allows to use HTTP digest authentication with OkHttp.

I have not checked if and how it is possible to combine all three pieces, however from my perspective this is the only way if you don't have the skills to implement HTTP digest auth on your own (as it requires cryptographic operations and is much more complex then HTTP basic auth for most people implementing HTTP digest auth as described in [rfc2617](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2617.txt) is unrealistic).